# How works python key=operator.itemgetter(1))?

Tags: python, matrix, key, operator-keyword

I have a matrix and I need to find max element and its number. How to rewrite it without operator (with for)?

```
    for j in range(size - 1):
        i, val = max(enumerate(copy[j::, j]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        copy = change_rows(copy, j, i)
        P = change_rows(P, j, i)
```

And actually maybe you can explain what this string means?

```
i, val = max(enumerate(copy[j::, j]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `np.argmax()`, which gets you the index of the largest value in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this line.

```py
i, val = max(enumerate(copy[j::, j]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

First, `enumerate()` creates an iterator over `copy[j::,j]` that yields index-value pairs. For example,

```py
>>> for i, val in enumerate("abcd"):
...     print(i, val)
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

Next, the `max()` function is for finding the largest item in a sequence. But we want it to target the values of `copy[j::,j]`, not the indices that we are also getting from `enumerate()`. Specifying `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` tells `max()` to look at the `(i,val)` pairs and find the one with the largest `val`.

This is probably better done with `np.argmax()`, especially because `val` goes unused.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> for j in range(size - 1):
...     i = np.argmax(copy[j::, j])    # Changed this line.
        copy = change_rows(copy, j, i)
        P = change_rows(P, j, i)
```